# Django file does not exist error when trying to attach pdf in email based on conditions

Tags: python, django, email-attachments, file-not-found, django-email

I am trying to send a 2 pdf files as attachment,1 generated by xhtml2pdf and another which is already present in the app directory of my django project, based on a condition. I am able to send the generated file and 1 file but getting error " File does not exist" for the other condition, even when both the files are in the same location.
I am a newbie here, what am i doing wrong? where and how do i need to store the files to be attached ?

my views code for email-

```
        patienthist = get_object_or_404(PatientHist, pk=email_id)  # stores values (Y,N)

        pdf = Render.render('eradicate/dietplan.html', context)
        msg = EmailMessage("Your Diet Plan", "Attached is your diet plan!", to=[email_id])
        msg.content_subtype = "html"
        msg.attach('my_pdf.pdf', pdf, 'application/pdf') # attaching generated pdf

        if patienthist.foodhabit == 'N':
            msg.attach_file('eradicate/LCHF Eradicate Diabetes.pdf') # doest not get attached
        else:
            msg.attach_file('eradicate/LFV Eradicate Diabetes.pdf')  # gets attached to email

        msg.send()
```

error i am getting-

```
FileNotFoundError at /eradicate/test@gmail.com/dietplan/

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'eradicate\\LCHF Eradicate Diabetes.pdf'

Exception Location: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\pathlib.py in _opener, line 1058
```

note: its adding an extra backslash after the app name eradicate, why does this happen?

my 2 files are stored in the django app directory, same level as that of views, models, admins etc.

Comment: Have you named the file correctly in the directory?

Comment: yes, i have double checked and verified.  Is it correct way to store the files like that? or am i supposed to be creating a separate folder like we do for templates?

Comment: Then, it could be a logical error with your condition ```if patienthist.foodhabit == 'N':``` Try attaching the file without this, and you can locate if this condition is failing somewhere in you code.

Comment: I just tried to remove my condition and upload just the 1 file.  it still gave the same error.

Comment: Thanks @Kshitij, there was an extra space in the file name before pdf i was trying to upload, now chaged it and its working. mistake on my part

Comment: Glad you found the error.